# Program stuck after completion

Tags: c++, string, turbo-c++

Why does this basic C++ program gets stuck after completion, it doesn't returns back to code in **TurboC++**. However, it works fine for words with 1 and 3 characters. It also runs perfectly in **CodeBlocks**.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char * name;
    cout<<"Enter your name : ";
    gets(name);
    int len = strlen(name);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cout<<name[i]<<" "<<i<<endl;
    }
    getch();
}
```

If I change **char*** to **char name[20]**, it works perfectly. Can anyone please explain the reason for it.
If their is problem in char *, then why does CodeBlocks runs it without any problem?

Comment: Why are you using TurboC++? That thing is at least 3 decades old! No wonder it doesn't work correctly, it was developed before C++ was standardized! Please use CodeBlocks with gcc or something else, but **not** TurboC++.

Comment: I know bro, but someone came to me with this doubt and I was not able to figure it out.

Comment: The variable `name` is a pointer, but where does it point? When you can answer that you know what's wrong.

Comment: Also, don't use `gets`. Never ever use `gets`. It is a bad function, and dangerous. It has also been removed from both the C and C++ standards.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). And please learn how to indent properly

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This question is clear and has a short compilable example.

Comment: Sorry guys, but even my teacher was Clueless when i asked her, that's why I posted it here.

Comment: Do feed back the answer *constructively* to your teacher.

Comment: I also do not understand downvotes. If question is trivial, it does not mean that it should be downvoted.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not compiler, and any C++ compilers working with it will not compile your code because there are a lot of problems with it: there's no `iostream.h`, `clrscr()` and `getch()` in C++. There are also no `cout` and `endl` in global namespace in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't allocate any memory for `name`.

The behaviour on using a pointer that doesn't point to any memory that you own is *undefined*.

That's why `char name[20];` works. Although `gets` is unsafe, as you can't control how many characters are read in so your character buffer could overrun. Why not use a `std::string`, `cin`, and a more up to date compiler?

Comment: @VaibhavVats please treat other users with respect. Also thank you comments are strongly discouraged. Better leave only the constructive part of your comment

Comment: actually both ;) If I am to be threatened better be with respect :) However I noticed the typo even before your commented

Comment: I am new to stack Overflow, so I am currently learning about the rules here. Sorry for any mistake.